# Extract a section of a line in a text file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to extract some specfic data from a pdf, I have managed to extract the text from the pdf and placed it into a txt file.  The data that is placed in the text file is one long line.  I need to extract a specfic part of the line.

If it starts with 'UK' and ends with '- -'

I have been trying using.

```
        Using read = New StreamReader(fName)
        Dim line As String = read.ReadToEnd
        If line.StartsWith(" UK") And line.Contains("- -") Then

        Else
            'do nothing
        End If

    End Using
```

`Startswith` doesn't work as the line doesn't start with 'UK'.  I can use `line.contains` as it does find UK but the line contains multiple instances of '- -'.

The section I need looks like the following

> UK (0.6085)* (£) 1.6435 -0.0062 0.8206 -0.0017 - -

I am using vb.net in MS Visual studio 2013.

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Which part of the string do you actually need to extract?

Comment: the string is hundreds of characters long and the section I want is highlighted above.

Comment: Okay, I thought you might actually need the numbers or a specific section.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Regex class:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("UK.*-\s?-\s?", RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(a)

If match.Success Then
    ' Do stuff
End If
```

Inside the If..Then you could loop through a series of matches via the Match.Captures collection property.

```
For Each c As Capture In result.Captures
    ' c.Value
Next
```

Regular expressions are a great tool for text matching, extraction, etc. get used to using them if you do a fair bit of this. I've found [RegexStudio](http://regexstudio.codeplex.com/) to be quite handy in testing .NET Regex patterns on the fly before I use them in code.

Answer (score 0):

How about StartWith and EndsWith.

```
if (src.StartsWith("UK") AND src.EndsWith("- -")) Then
    'True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
If line like "*UK*- -" then
    'do something
Else
    'do nothing
End If
```